# Can't parse json from php into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, web

Just started learning JS and, I'm using W3schools to learn, so i get to the JSON PHP section and it comes this example:

JS Code

```
      const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      
      xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        const myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "/php/demo_file.php");
      xmlhttp.send();
```

demo_file.php

```
<?php
$myObj = new stdClass();
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
?>
```

I get this error:

[image: Error]

Like I said, I'm just learning and this seems like a trivial problem, the demo is working on the w3schools website but not working on my editor.

Comment: Check the PHP file first in your browser, to see if it does indeed return JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run php on a local server. PHP cannot be run anywhere on your document. You need to install xampp or apache.

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but you're not expressing it very well. _"PHP cannot be run anywhere on your document."_, don't you mean: _"A PHP script does not execute in the browser, like Javascript, it needs a webserver with a PHP interpreter. Running a PHP script directly from your computer will not work."_.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you are right. English is not my first language. I try to do my best. Your choice of words is better.